# Powershell adding file sizes, unexpected result

Tags: powershell, filesize

I am currently working on a powershell script to copy a random selection of songs from my NAS onto an SD card. As an added complication, I can have no more than 512 songs per folder and also obviously, need to stop the process before I run out of free space on the card.

I have written a nearly complete script (with reduced amounts of songs for testing purposes), but am struggling with keeping track of the total size of the files I have copied. As an example, a test run with a total of 112MB of files gives a recorded value (in $copied_size) of 1245. I don't know what that value means, it doesn't seem to be a realistic value of GB, Gb, MB or Mb. I am obviously missing something here. Any ideas?

Here is the script, I haven't put in the size restriction yet:

```
$j = 1
$i = 0
$files_per_folder = 5
$sd_card_size = 15920000000
$copied_size = 0
$my_path = '\\WDMYCLOUD\Public\Shared Music'
$random = Get-Random -Count 100 -InputObject (1..200)
For ($j=1; $j -le 5; $j++)
{
    md ("F:\" + $j)
    $list = Get-ChildItem -Path $my_path | ?{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Extension -eq '.mp3'}
    For ($i=0; $i -le $files_per_folder - 1; $i++)
    {
        Copy-Item -Path ($my_path + "\" + $list[$random[(($J - 1) * $files_per_folder) +$i]]) -Destination ('F:\' + $j)
        $copied_size = $copied_size + ($my_path + "\" + $list[$random[(($J - 1) * $files_per_folder) +$i]]).length
    }
}
Write-Host "Copied Size =  " $copied_size
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `Get-PSDrive` to look at the size/usage of the SD card?

Comment: Short answer - because I don't really know what I'm doing. I've only recently been playing with powershell, having used the command line for years. I have been researching Get-PSDrive since seeing your comment, but can only find reference of it outputting a table of information to the screen. How do you go about extracting just the free space on the disc and using that in a formula?

Comment: `Get-PSDrive <driveletter> | Select Free, Used` is a short way

Comment: The nearest thing I have found is  $free_space = Get-PSDrive F | Select-Object Free  but that just seems to pass a table with the free space to the variable as a string. Just literally found this as you were posting your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's *a way* to solve your problem using some more powershell-like patterns.  It compares the current file to be copied with space remaining and will exit out of the top-level loop if that condition is true.

```
#requires -Version 3

$path = '\\share\Public\Shared Music'
$filesPerFolder = 5
$copySize = 0
$random = 1..200 | Get-Random -Count 100

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Filter *.mp3

:main
for ($i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++) {
    $dest = New-Item -Path F:\$i -ItemType Directory -Force

    for ($j = 0; $j -le $filesPerFolder; $j++) {
        $file = $files[$random[(($j - 1) * $filesPerFolder) + $i]]
        if ((Get-PSDrive -Name F).Free -lt $file.Length) {
            break main
        }

        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $dest\
        $copySize += $file.Length
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TheIncorrigible, that solved the problem. All pretty much working now. I just had to make a few tweaks and additions, such as swap the j and the i around in line 13 and add a $fileCount variable and add it to the conditions to break out of :main, as I found that I ran out of songs before the card was full. I did away with $copysize as it is no longer needed. Thank you again.